# How/Where to host an UDP based component?

Tags: .net, hosting, udp

I´m working on a project that basically will show some data collected from hardware devices through **UDP** protocol.
the first idea of how to do this: implement a winService (to listen and persist the messages) and a wepApp to manage the data, based on .NET platform.

I´m confused about if exists the possibility to rent a "windows service" hosting, to deploy the "udp listener" component.

thanx,!
Gorsh

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A shared hosting setup will not allow you to have the permissions needed to run your service, look for a managed hosting service or a VPS on a cloud.  Amazon EC2 or GoGrid currently have Microsoft Windows cloud offerings.